# Error with newcommand and \def

Tags: nodes, chemfig

Can anyone ples help with this problem:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=a4,headsepline]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}  
\def\nc{\arrow{0}[,0]}  

\begin{document}  
What it is:  
\schemedebug{true}  
\schemestart  
\chemfig{A}  
\chemsign{+}  
\chemfig{A}  
\arrow{->}  
\chemfig{C}  
\schemestop  

What I want:  
\schemedebug{true}  
\schemestart  
\chemfig{A}\arrow{0}[,0]  
\chemsign{+}\arrow{0}[,0]  
\chemfig{A}  
\arrow{->}  
\chemfig{C}  
\schemestop  

the usage of arrow{0}[,0] is very annoying, so I tried this:  
%\schemedebug{true}  
%\schemestart  
%\chemfig{A}\nc  
%\chemsign{+}\nc  
%\chemfig{A}  
%\arrow{->}  
%\chemfig{C}  
%\schemestop  
\end{document}
```

But all I get is this error:

```
%! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \node
```

Comment: Note to readers:  it is the commented section of code that causes the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a scheme (i.e. between `\schemestart` and `\schemestop`) the `\arrow` commands needs to be used directly and not hidden in a macro. But there are other possibilities.

In order to use your `\nc` macro as a shortcut for `\arrow{0}[,0]` `chemfig`'s scheme mechanism must treat it like it treats `\arrow`. That can be achieved rather easily by patching `\CF@schemestart@v`. Currently it looks for the tokens `\arrow`, `merge` and `\schemestop` and collects all other macros as part of the node (or “compound”) text. With the help of `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` the macro `\nc` can be added to the list:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\CF@schemestart@v
  {\arrow}%    search
  {\arrow\nc}% replace
  {}%          success
  {}%          failure
\makeatother
```

Then `\nc` can be used as the shortcut you want:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=a4,headsepline]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage{chemfig,etoolbox}

\newcommand\nc{\arrow{0}[,0]}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\CF@schemestart@v
  {\arrow}%    search
  {\arrow\nc}% replace
  {}%          success
  {}%          failure
\makeatother

\begin{document}  
\schemedebug{true}

\schemestart
  \chemfig{A}\nc
  \chemsign{+}\nc
  \chemfig{A}
  \arrow{->}
  \chemfig{C}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*Original answer that assumed that the question was about spacing:*

I'd use `chemfig`'s `\+` instead of `\chemsign{+}`. The latter was introduced before `chemfig` had the possibilities for schemes. The `\+` is designed to be used inside schemes and it is possible to set the spacing before and after the `+` it typesets with

```
\setandsign{<dim before>}{<dim after>}{<vertical offset>}
```

This can also be adjusted on a per case basis as `\+` has an optional argument (with braces!):

```
\+{<dim before>,<dim after>,<vertical offset>}
```

The macro is described in the manual in part IV *Reaction schemes* section 12 *The + sign*.

Also keep in mind that everything between two `\arrow` commands is placed in *one* node. Inside a node ends of lines will be treated as spaces like everywhere else in LaTeX:

```
\schemestart
  % first node:
  \chemfig{A}
  \chemsign{+}
  \chemfig{A}
  \arrow{->}
  % second node:
  \chemfig{A}%  hide end of line
  \chemsign{+}% hide end of line
  \chemfig{A}
\schemestop
```

[image]

Using `\+`:

```
\schemestart
  \chemfig{A}
  \+
  \chemfig{A}
  \arrow{->}
  \chemfig{C}
\schemestop

\schemestart
  \chemfig{A}%
  \+%
  \chemfig{A}
  \arrow{->}
  \chemfig{C}
\schemestop

\setandsign{0pt,0pt,0pt}
\schemestart
  \chemfig{A}%
  \+%
  \chemfig{A}
  \arrow{->}
  \chemfig{C}
\schemestop
```

[image]

Comment: What prevents the use of `\arrow` in a macro?

Comment: (I haven't looked too closely into the source of `chemfig` so the following may actually be wrong) The scheme commands look for the _token_ `\arrow` and if it is inside a macro it is not found and as a consequence collected as part of the node text. Instead it should end the current node and start a new one...

Comment: I know about the `\+`, but its annoying to center the + in every reaction with the vertical offset. If it's possible to make the + a stand alone compound by default  the code for long reaction schemes would be much more nicer. (that was my intention with `\arrow{0}[,0]`)

Comment: @flamel that wasn't clear from your question! I assumed you wanted to reduce the spacing (which was the only visual difference in the outcome of you MWE)....

Comment: @flamel please see my edited answer